# How to check for server-side rendering and client-side rendering using the service worker of a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, service-worker, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, content-script

In the specific example, the website I am targeting uses Next.js. I do not have the ability to see any of the pre-bundled source code. However, I figured out that they make use of the `next/link` or `<Link>` component to handle client-side navigation between routes.

The page contents are fetched via a private API. Afterwards, the URL is changed via the url object.

I have trouble finding a suitable way to check whether the page is being loaded by e.g. clicking the refresh button in the browser or clicking into the browser bar and hitting enter (i.e. server-side rendering), or just by navigating between the routes using page navigation (client-side rendering).

I want to be able to pass messages between the content script of my chrome extension and the service worker, whenever either rendering takes place, indicating which of the two it was specifically. The content script first fires sometime between `window.onload` and `"document_end"` [[1]](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/#run_time).

#### Last attempt (service-worker.js)

```js
const isPageReload = (url) => {
  return url === undefined;
};

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  if (isPageReload(changeInfo.url)) {
    console.log('Page was reloaded');
  } else {
    console.log('Page was not reloaded');
  }
});
```

#### Second to last attempt (service-worker.js)

Here both events logs are returned in the case of client-side rendering and the log `'Page was not reloaded'` is returned in the case of server-side rendering. Both of which are obviously not what I want to achieve. I have also tried the following for detecting client-side rendering, however, that approach does not pick up the server-side rendering at all:

```js
const clientSideRoutingListener = async () => {
    console.log('Client-side routing occurred');
    // Your custom code here
    const [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true});
    const response = await chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {event: "client-side-routing"});
    // do something with response here, not outside the function
    console.log(response);
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if (request.event === 'receiving-end-exists') {
            if (chrome.webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated.hasListener(clientSideRoutingListener)) return;
            // Listen for the onHistoryStateUpdated event
            chrome.webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated.addListener(clientSideRoutingListener, {url: [{schemes: ['http', 'https']}]}); // Listen for events on HTTP and HTTPS pages
            sendResponse({event: "clientSideRoutingListener added"});
        }
    }
);
```

Does anybody know an approach that works and might even be elegant?

Comment: To detect client-side navigation you can use `navigation.onnavigate` event in the content script. The server navigation will cause a new page to be constructed so your content script will run again - this fact itself is the indication. P.S. use `sender.tab.id` instead of chrome.tabs.query.